# Adjust short delay when calendar appears in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know if there is any possibility of adjusting a brief delay I have when I run my app. If you run it, you'll notice that the calendar appears after my two `selectinput`. I find this a little strange. Is there any possibility to adjust this?

Thank you very much!

Executable code below:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(tidyr)
    library(lubridate)
    
    function.cl<-function(dt){
      df <- structure(
        list(date = c("01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021",
                      "08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021",
                      "13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021"),
             D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8),
             DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
             DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7),
             DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)),
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
      
      df$date <- parse_date_time(df$date, c('ymd', 'dmy'))
      
      scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
        dta %>%
          filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
          summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
          pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
          mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
          plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
      }  
      Plot1<-scatter_date(dt)
      
      return(list(
        "Plot1" = Plot1, 
        date = df$date
      ))
    }
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                              br(),
                              
                              tabPanel("",
                                       sidebarLayout(
                                         sidebarPanel(
                                          
                                            uiOutput("dated"),
                                           selectInput("day", label = h4("Week"),""),
                                           selectInput("code", label = h4("Type"),""),
                                           br(),
                                           
                                         ),
                                         
                                         mainPanel(
                                           tabsetPanel(
                                             tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600"))),
                                         ))
                              )))
    
    
    server <- function(input, output,session) {
      data <- reactive(function.cl("2021-08-01"))
      
      output$dated <- renderUI({
        all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
        disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
        dateInput(input = "date", 
                  label = "Select Date",
                  min = min(data()$date),
                  max = max(data()$date),
                 
                  format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                  datesdisabled = disabled)
      })
      
      output$Graph <- renderPlot({
        req(input$date)
        function.cl(input$date)[["Plot1"]]
        
      })
    
    
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Because the date input is in a uiOutput, I think it will always render after the select inputs. The select inputs will exist once the program starts, where as the render UI has to wait for the server to process it or something like that.  You could always put both select inputs in the same date uiOutput (wrap the date and both select inputs in a div or fluidrow).

Comment: Silentdevildoll, I like your idea. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that they all appear at the same time, perhaps you can wrap your `selectInput`s in a `tagList()` in the same `renderUI` as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(
  list(date = c("01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021",
                "08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021",
                "13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021"),
       D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8),
       DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
       DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7),
       DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  dta %>%
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
}

function.cl<-function(dt,df){
  df$date <- parse_date_time(df$date, c('ymd', 'dmy'))
  
  Plot1<-scatter_date(dt,df)
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = Plot1, 
    date = df$date
  ))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("dated"),
                                       #selectInput("day", label = h4("Week"),""),
                                       #selectInput("code", label = h4("Type"),""),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600"))),
                                     ))
                          )))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl("2021-08-01",df))
  
  output$dated <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    tagList(
      dateInput(input = "date", 
                label = "Select Date",
                min = min(data()$date),
                max = max(data()$date),
                value = min(data()$date),
                format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                datesdisabled = disabled),
      selectInput("day", label = h4("Week"),""),
      selectInput("code", label = h4("Type"),"")
    )
    
  })
  
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date)
    function.cl(input$date,df)[["Plot1"]]
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: YBS,I did as you suggested, but the two selectinput did not appear. Appeared to you?

Comment: Yes, they do appear.  You should comment out the `selectInput`s on the 'ui' side.  I can post the full code if you want.

Comment: I did it, but I didn't feel any difference. If you can post I appreciate it!

Comment: Please note that I have kept the dataframe `df` and function `scatter_date()` outside the main function.  You can keep them inside, if you wish.